# How to assign empty link on firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

I tried `<a href="#"></a>`. It didn't worked for [firefox](/questions/tagged/firefox):

```
<a href="#" id="home" onClick="changeContent('frontmain');"><span>Home</span></a>
```

It has a javascript function changeContent.

The code works for every browsers expect Firefox open new page on every click.

I have also tried follow code:

```
<a href="javascript:;" id="home" onClick="changeContent('frontmain');"><span>Home</span></a>
```

it still didn't work. Firefox opens `about:blank` new browser page.

Any help would be appreciated.Thank you

Comment: Show code for this changeContent('frontmain');

Comment: Please change the title of your question. [**Learn how to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want a piece of text change when you click it. Not sure what exactly you want to achieve, but you most likely don't need the `<a>` element for this.

Make a `<span>`, `<div>` or `<button>` element, style it with css and add your onclick event handler there.

```
<span role="button" tabindex="0" class="styleMe" onclick="changeContent('frontmain');">Home</span>
```

The "role" attribute helps to clarify the intended use as a button for accessibility.

The "tabindex" attribute allows to navigate to this action without using a mouse.

You probably want to set the cursor css attribute in your styling to visualize that it's clickable.

```
span.styleMe{
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

The reason, besides having to deal with the href issue is that I personally always associate anchor elements with navigating away from the current page and due to a slow internet connection I never use them directly always open in another tab.

I always want to let it load in a new tab while I continue browsing the current page, because a new page takes several minutes to load on average.

That's why I suggest to make a clear distinction between "a click that will make you wait minutes and loose the page you waited several minutes to load unless you choose an alternative open-in-new-tab-option" and "a click that will instantly change the content of the current page or instantly scroll to a place somewhere on the same page"

Comment: An `a` tag with an `href` has the semantic information that something will happen on a click. `p` or `b` have just structural informations. So if you suggest to use those you should also suggest to use _aria_

Comment: Not sure what you mean exactly, could you please clarify what you mean with "semantic/structural information" and "something will happen"?

Comment: Nevermind, I googled it. Thanks for pointing it out. I apologize that I didn't think about it in my initial suggestion.

Comment: One small suggestion, while it is not necessarily wrong to use `p` with a role `button` in this particular case a _neutral_ tag like `span` or `div` would be better, as the `p` has the meaning _paragraph_. (And as it seems that it is for navigation I still would probably stay with an `a` tag, but that something more opinion based)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on [onClick](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp) event description. As you can read the **onClick** event can be used nearly within all HTML elements. Therefore it would be better not using the `A` element. Use element `P` or `SPAN` or a button decorated using CSS to make it clear that a visitor can click on it to change something.

Comment: If you're going to use a `<p>` or `<span>` element, add `tabindex="0"` to the element so users that navigate with the keyboard can activate the action.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question is open to debate. An excellent discussion regarding this topic can be found here: [Which "href" value should I use for JavaScript links, "#" or "javascript:void(0)"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134845/href-attribute-for-javascript-links-or-javascriptvoid0)